# Multiprocessing shared numpy array

Tags: numpy, multiprocessing

I need to share numpy array between Processes, to store in it some results. Im not quite sure if what I have done so far is correct. This is my simplified code.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Array
import numpy as np

def worker(shared,lock):
    numpy_arr = np.frombuffer(shared.get_obj())
    # do some work ...  
    with lock:
        for i in range(10):
            numpy_arr[0] += 1
        numpy_arr += 1
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':

    jobs = []
    lock = Lock()

    shared_array = Array('d', 1000000)


    for process in range(4):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(shared_array,lock))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for process in jobs:
        process.join()

    m = np.frombuffer(shared_array.get_obj())
    np.save('data', m)
    print (m[:5])
```

From this code i obtain expected results, but again, Im not sure if this is the correct way. And finally, what is the diffrence between multiprocessing.Array and multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Array ?